# Re-using custom format in android xml

Tags: android, xml, enums

Consider a custom xml enum defined as

```
<attr name="myProperty">
    <enum name="None" value="0"/>
    <enum name="One" value="1"/>
    <enum name="Two" value="2"/>
    <enum name="Three" value="3"/>
    <enum name="Four" value="4"/>
    <enum name="Five" value="5"/>
    <enum name="Six" value="6"/>
    <enum name="Seven" value="7"/>
    <enum name="Eight" value="8"/>
    <enum name="Nine" value="9"/>
    <enum name="Ten" value="10"/>
</attr>
```

I am consuming this enum as follows

```
<declare-styleable name="MyUnrelatedControl">
    <attr name="myProperty" />
</declare-stylable>
```

But the problem is suppose I have two attributes of same format(custom enum), how can I achieve that. For example

```
<declare-styleable name="MyUnrelatedControl">
    <attr name="unrelatedControl1" /> <!-- format=myProperty -->
    <attr name="unrelatedControl2" /> <!-- format=myProperty -->
</declare-stylable>
```

Consider this like margin-left, margin-right, margin-top, margin-bottom all of the same format `Dimension`. Similarly I want to define a format and use it for different attributes in the same declare-stylable.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I doubt whether a solution exists. Had a look the way it is used in framework. The enum is repeated in both `layout_width` and `layout_height` definition. You can see it in this [attrs.xml](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/attrs.xml?av=f)

Answer (score 4):

There is no solution. The reason being that such enum definitions are **not** supposed to be reused. For every property you need to define a separate set of possible values. This is evident when you look into Androids [**attrs.xml**](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/attrs.xml):

```
<declare-styleable name="ViewGroup_Layout">
    <!-- Specifies the basic width of the view.  This is a required attribute
         for any view inside of a containing layout manager.  Its value may
         be a dimension (such as "12dip") for a constant width or one of
         the special constants. -->
    <attr name="layout_width" format="dimension">
        <!-- The view should be as big as its parent (minus padding).
             This constant is deprecated starting from API Level 8 and
             is replaced by {@code match_parent}. -->
        <enum name="fill_parent" value="-1" />
        <!-- The view should be as big as its parent (minus padding).
             Introduced in API Level 8. -->
        <enum name="match_parent" value="-1" />
        <!-- The view should be only big enough to enclose its content (plus padding). -->
        <enum name="wrap_content" value="-2" />
    </attr>

    <!-- Specifies the basic height of the view.  This is a required attribute
         for any view inside of a containing layout manager.  Its value may
         be a dimension (such as "12dip") for a constant height or one of
         the special constants. -->
    <attr name="layout_height" format="dimension">
        <!-- The view should be as big as its parent (minus padding).
             This constant is deprecated starting from API Level 8 and
             is replaced by {@code match_parent}. -->
        <enum name="fill_parent" value="-1" />
        <!-- The view should be as big as its parent (minus padding).
             Introduced in API Level 8. -->
        <enum name="match_parent" value="-1" />
        <!-- The view should be only big enough to enclose its content (plus padding). -->
        <enum name="wrap_content" value="-2" />
    </attr>
</declare-styleable>
```

As you can see `layout_width` and `layout_height` are exactly the same, but a separate `<attr />` is defined for each of them. This is then used in much the same manner as you are trying to:

```
<declare-styleable name="ViewGroup_MarginLayout">
    <attr name="layout_width" />
    <attr name="layout_height" />
    ...
</declare-styleable>
```

So it seems that what you are trying to do is impossible.